# FullCalendar viewRender: Append text in listDay-View

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, viewrendering

I'm using [FullCalendar by Adam Shaw](https://plugins.jquery.com/fullcalendar/).

To show all events on a day, I'm using the listday-view. I need to show a link in the header of the table.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {  
    if(view.name === 'listDay') {
        element.find('.fc-widget-header').append( '<span>&raquo; My Text</span>' );
    }
}
```

It seems, that the element is not been found. A "jQuery-alert" instead of the "element.find" works.

Comment: The docs for this event say "This callback will trigger after the view has been fully rendered". So in theory your code ought to work. `element` does appear to contain all those sub elements including the one you're targeting. Stumped me, as well :-|.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `viewRender callback` runs before the `.fc-widget-header` element has been rendered and can't be found.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/

You can add your code in the `eventAfterAllRender callback` because as i can see the `listDay` will rendered only if there are events to show.

example

```
eventAfterAllRender : function (view) {  
    if(view.name === 'listDay') {
        view.el.find('.fc-widget-header').append( '<span>&raquo; My Text</span>' );
    }
}
```